# why is my key_name value not as i set it?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

First off, I'm relatively new to Google App Engine, so I'm probably doing something silly.

I want the username to be set as key in model User

```
class User(db.Model):
#username is key
    password = db.StringProperty(required = True) 
    type = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    approved = db.BooleanProperty(required = True)
```

To insert i do this

```
user = User(key_name = self.request.get('username'), password = password, type = type, approved = False)
user.put()
```

I believe that when you set key_name manually it should be exactly what you set it to be but when i query user modle

```
users = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User")
for(user in users):
    self.response.write(user.key())

I got the output as agxkZXZ-dmhvc3RlbDNyEQsSBFVzZXIiB2JodXNoYW4M
```

Please someone help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with you should read the docs on the Key class https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass and how keys a structured - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Kinds_keys_and_identifiers

Any way to your problem, note that the output of `self.response.write(user.key())` is giving you the string `agxkZXZ-dmhvc3RlbDNyEQsSBFVzZXIiB2JodXNoYW4M` which is correct behaviour.

This is a URL safe form of the key which encodes all artifacts that make up the key.

This means you can round trip

```
user.key() = db.Key(encoded=str(user.key())
```

This allows you to use keys as part of URL.  Whether that's wise or not is another discussion.

If you want to just show the name you used as the `key_name` then the docs for the `Key` class show you that the method `name()` will return the name.

As in `user.key().name()` or you could use `id_or_name` method which does what the name implies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `self.request.get('username')` is returning Null or None, and that results in the Datastore generating a default entry.  According to the [Users Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects) documentation it might need `users.get_current_user().nickname()` instead.  Check by [logging](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Logging) the values.

As Tim says you retrieve the name from the key using `user.key().name()`.